# AWS CLI does not detect ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services

It seems a simple task, but somehow it fails: AWS client does not see the credentials specified in `~/.aws/credentials`. The file looks following way:

```
[me]
aws_access_key_id=xxxx
aws_secret_access_key=yyyyy

[alter_ego]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=yyyyy
```

I am using `awscli-1.11.128` on python3. When I run `aws configure list` (with or without sudo), I am getting:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

I tried to set the `AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE` to no avail:

```
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

those are non-default credential groups, so you will have to explicitly select them like this:

`$ aws --profile alter_ego configure list`

`$ aws --profile me configure list`